# Selenium Python: Not finding element which clearly exists

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to click through the levels of a site's navigation using python and selenium. The navbar contains list items that have subelements within them.

Here is the html of the navbar:

[image]

The objective here is to find the element with id="ts_time", to hover over it and to click on the element within it.

So far I have tried the following selection types:

- ID
- XPath
- Class_Name

Here is the ID.

```
time_menu_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ts_time")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(time_menu_button)

time.sleep(2.5)
```

This results in a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: You say you are trying to find the element with the id "ts_time" but your code is trying to find "#imgLogo"

Comment: Please post the entire code and error stack to check which line it is breaking? Please post the text based HTML not the snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

To hover over the element with `id="ts_time"` you need to invoke `perform()` and then to click on the element within it you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
time_menu_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li#ts_time")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(time_menu_button).peform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li#ts_time > a"))).click()
```

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This results in 'TimeoutException.' Seems like that isn't finding the element either